# Нормален ли подобный стиль в C++?

Tags: c++

```
stream
    << this->x << ','
    << this->y << ','
    << this->z << '\n'
    ;
return stream;

вместо:

stream << this->x << ',';
stream << this->y << ',';
stream << this->z << '\n';
return stream;
```

Comment: а почему нет? Перегруженные операции с потоками всегда должны возращать ссылку на поток, так что вполне.

Answer (score 7):

Можно даже

```
return stream
    << this->x << ','
    << this->y << ','
    << this->z << '\n';
```

Все равно вы в обоих вариантах каждый вывод не проверяете, так что разницы нет...